# WPF Animation hooked on Mouse / Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **custom wpf user control** with an animation, that should be **spawned at the mouse position** (for example a shrinking circle). Currently I'm placing this control in a **window**, that is transparent and center it at the current cursor position.

---

However, this seems to be inefficent, because when moving the mouse fast, the placement of the transparent window is to slow and laggy.

**Is there a another way or a better solution to place a custom wpf usercontrol with an animation at the current mouse position (even outside of the application)?**

Comment: Consider putting a `Canvas` in your window and the animation in that `Canvas`, but hidden. Then when the event occurs that causes the animation to run, move it to the mouse cursor's position, unhide it and start the animation. When the animation finishes, hide the animation.